# Wordpress admin section cleanup?

Tags: wordpress, admin

Anybody knows a good plugin for Wordpress to provide a nice Admin dashboard which also cleans the regular Wordpress update mess. I do not want customer getting distracted with the loaded content in the backend with events, news and updates (messy content updates) in the Backend login? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be better on ServerFault... Not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're needing. If you're looking for a way to hide a lot of the stuff in the WordPress control panel, Adminimize is a good plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/

There are also plugins to hide the update reminder: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hide-update-reminder/

And to control what appears on the add/edit post page: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-cms-post-control/

Using a combination of the above, you can redirect users directly to the post page (skipping the dashboard) when they log in, and limit what they see in the control panel menu to an amazing extent. You can allow them to see widgets, for instance, but not see the themes page.

Hope this helps.
Michelle

Answer (score 0):

In the latest WordPress versions, >2.7, you can set the admin screen to display only a subset of the Admin widgets.

Just click on Screen Options at the top right of the Admin page to reveal option checkboxes.

For example, you can uncheck "WordPress Development Blog", and "Other WordPress News". You can even format the screen to be just one column and only show the "QuickPress" widget.